# How to show loading image on method/action executing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new for PHP/CodeIgniter.

I want to show loading image when action/method is started for executing and at the end of page loading it will hide/stop showing loading image.

Following is my action in controller:

```
public function Index() {
    $this->data['Shibirarthis'] = $this->Shibirarthi_m->get_by(array('IsDeleted !=' => 1));
    $this->data['subview'] = 'Shibirarthi/Index';
    $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: you need javascript/jquery and ajax for that

Comment: @MeeneshJain How can I handle localhost:8080/GurukulBalShibir/Shibirarthi/Index  using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Hi put this in HTML page:

**HTML**

```
<div id="loader">
   <img src=""> //put image you want
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#loader').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Hope this will help you... :)